# Counting SQL Server Transactions

Tags: sql-server

Is there a method to count total transactions by type (read/write) by day/hour/peak?

Comment: You mean historically, or going forward? If historically, no, SQL Server doesn't track this information for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the performance counters `Transactions/sec` and `Write Transactions/sec` documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189883.aspx